# Изменение цвета иконки в Toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

Есть Activity и несколько Fragment которые открываются внутри этого активити.
Toolbar находится в активити.

в Toolbar есть бургер иконка и одна иконка из OptionsMenu.
В некоторых фрагментах нужно менять цвет иконок в Toolbar(цвет бургера и всех других иконок).

Например, в первом фрагменте стандартный цвет из темы, а во втором красный, а если нажимаем назад и возвращаемся на первый то сново цвет стандартный из темы..

Как это более корректно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам в каждом фрагменте нужно это делать через функцию:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
          inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)   

    }
```

и дальше вы находите нужную вам кнопку:

```
val item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh); // например у меня так
```

либо делаете все через when (так на котлине, либо switch), и дальше берете вашу картинку которая присвоена данной кнопке и меняете цвет у ее drawable:

```
Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_refresh_white_24dp);
icon.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
item.setIcon(icon);
```

на java я думаю все тоже очевидно и понятно, в случае если работаете на java.